# uploading files from phone to dropbox in android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am a newbie to Android development. I am writing an app for my research group. I would like to upload the data (.txt) files which were written in android phone to our research group dropbox. Anybody knows any references about uploading a file to dropbox?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you browse to Dropbox.com and upload them through the web interface?

Comment: But, we are deploying the phones to elderly people for the research purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way. I think it help you.

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/385431/Android-RESTful-OAuth-upload-file-to-Dropbox)
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819829/using-dropbox-api-to-upload-a-file-with-android)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk