# Cannot upload file to dropbox ANDROID

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, android-file

I'm having trouble uploading file to Dropbox. I do not get any errors, the app folder is created in my account, but the file is not uploaded to dropbox. Here is my code:

```
public void exportDataInCSV(final String file_name,
            final ArrayList<Assessment> assessments, final boolean dropBox)
            throws IOException {

        final File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/MYDIR");

        boolean var = false;
        if (!folder.exists())
            var = folder.mkdir();

        System.out.println("" + var);

        final String filename = folder.toString() + "/" + file_name + ".csv";

        // show waiting screen
        CharSequence contentTitle = getString(R.string.app_name);

        final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(DataExport.this,
                contentTitle, "Exporting data...", true);// please
                                                            // wait

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);

                    fw.append("MYNAME");
                    fw.append(',');

                    fw.append("MYSIRNAME");

                    fw.close();
                    if (dropBox) {

                        File file = new File(folder.toString() + "/"
                                + file_name + ".csv");
                        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        Entry response = mDBApi.putFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
                                inputStream, file.length(), null, null);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

So can someone help me and tell me how can I upload the file i'm creating using the filewriter to Dropbox, that is also saved to the phone's SD card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uploading files from phone to dropbox in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146186/uploading-files-from-phone-to-dropbox-in-android)