# Upload image to Dropbox with sync API from FileInputStream

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm fighting with dropbox sync SDK (Android) to upload some images to my dropbox private Aplication folder, the problem is when I have a FileInputStream dont know what method need to use for upload

this is a portion of the code:

```
uploadImg=(ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.uploadi);   
        uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mDbxAcctMgr.hasLinkedAccount()) {
                try {
                    DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());
                    DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, items.get(position));

                    if (!dbxFs.exists(testPath)) {
                        dbxFs.createFolder(testPath);
                        getData(ids.get(position));
                        int cont = 0;

                        for(int i=0; i<f.size(); i++){
                            File tmpFile;
                            FileInputStream fis;    
                            tmpFile = new File(f.get(i), cont+".jpg");
                            cont++;
                            fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
                            DbxPath filePath = new DbxPath(testPath, items.get(position)); 
//CODE TO UPLOAD FILE

                        }
                    }

                } catch (Unauthorized e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } 
            else { } //!haslinked

            }

        });
```

I've searched in

[link1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile)

and here

[link2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android)

but the info not be intuitive for upload files from existing file.

Also I've founded [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819829/using-dropbox-api-to-upload-a-file-with-android) and [**this**](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) but needs to create  a `private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi` and when I try to define eclipse show me a error. "DropboxAPI cannot be resolved to a type"

Somebody can I help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [writeFromExistingFile](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFile.writeFromExistingFile) method in the Sync SDK to write an existing local file into Dropbox. (The last two links you have are for the Core SDK, which is entirely different.)