# Is there a way to upload file to Google Drive from InputStream in Drive SDK?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have to load some data to Google Drive, but I can't use [recommended by Drive SDK way to do it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert):

```
FileContent fileContent = new FileContent(mimeType, dataFile);
try {
  File file = service.files().insert(body, fileContent).execute();
  return file;
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
  return null;
}
```

because my data isn't always has the java.io.File as a source. Sometimes it may be an InputStream from encrypted storage or from other cloud storage and therefore I can't get FileContent from it. Is there a way to load data from InputStream to Google Drive without their intermediate storing on file system (as for [Dropbox API method "putFileOverwrite"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832865/753575), for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out

```
 File file= drive.files().insert(body,
                                new InputStreamContent(
                                        fileItemStream
                                                .getContentType(),
                                        new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                                IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream)))).execute;
```